# Automate log conversion as Action in Vector CANoe

Tags: canoe

CANoe offers an option **Actions** in the Export and Logging Settings window. The help window says:

> An action defines an application that is called after saving the
> target file.

What I'd like to achieve is something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600080/is-there-a-way-to-automate-blf-to-csv-conversion-in-vector-canoe): have all the logs from the application happen in BLF format using a single logging block (for performance reasons, I don't want to put a lot of logging blocks in the simulation), then set up an action to automatically convert the BLF file to ASC. Yes, I could write an helper program opening CANoe via COM, but I'd like not to. Somebody from Vector told me once that the only portion of CANoe certified for ISO26262 is the CLI, but it doesn't sound right to me.

I can't even get started on this, as I cannot find any documentation about using CANoe via CLI. Does anybody knows how to do this (if it can be done)?

EDIT: in the **CANoe RT Server: Command Line Control** portion of the help manual, it says (emphasys mine):

> Configuration and control of the CANoe RT server is mainly done via
> the CANoe dialog on the user PC in Options dialog (Extensions|CANoe
> RT). *In addition you can also control Runtime Server and Runtime
> Kernel via command line input on the server host.*

so they have CLI for something. I'm afraid the answer might be that is not feasible because Vector wants to enforce COM interface as the only interface for automation pipelines (see also Jenkins integration)

Comment: Directly logging as ASC is not an option? If not, why?

Comment: @M.Spiller not an option due to company constraints. Need to have BLF, want to use text-based analysis approach myself, don't want to manually re-parse everything.

Answer (score 0):

The question which you are referring to uses COM interface for performing the conversion.
A suggestion for you is to create an application which open a new CANoe window and then make the conversion and close immediately(similar to the one in the question you referred).
Then, you can start the application via the **Actions** feature.

NOTE: There are no CLIs to control the CANoe application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I might have understood this the wrong way around (see edit to question), I am referring to Actions, that I can configure in the Actions tab under Options > External Programs > Actions. No need to script COM mambojumbo for that. But, need to have CLI interface to recursively call CANoe for that...